# I have two vectors of indices (rows, columns) for a data.frame with corresponding values, whats the fastest way to build the new data.frame?

Tags: r, indexing

I have a data frame with 3 columns (df1). Two of which represent the indices of a new data.frame (df2) and the remaining column contains the values that shall be placed in df2. I'm sorry if i have overlooked the right answer.

```
  df1 <- data.frame(
row = c(1,3,1,2,3),
col = c(2,2,1,2,1),
value = c(1:5)
)
```

As output i want the following:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| NA | 4 |
| 5 | 2 |

Is there a way of achieving this without having to iterate through the table (or apply)?
I want to speed up my functions so a fast way would be very helpful. Thanks in advance!

The following does not work as desired:

```
df2 <- data.frame(matrix( nrow = 3, ncol = 2 ))

df2[df1$row, df1$col] <- df1$value
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to provide the row and column indices as `matrix`. `cbind` can create of those two vectors the row and column `matrix`.

```
df2 <- data.frame(matrix( nrow = 3, ncol = 2 ))
df2[cbind(df1$row, df1$col)] <- df1$value
df2
#  X1 X2
#1  3  1
#2 NA  4
#3  5  2
```

Or better (faster, less memory consumption) filling the `matrix` and converting it afterwards to a `data.frame`.

```
df2 <- matrix(NA_integer_, 3, 2)
df2[cbind(df1$row, df1$col)] <- df1$value
df2 <- as.data.frame(df2)
```

Or do it in one step.

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(`[<-`(matrix(NA, 3, 2), cbind(df1$row, df1$col), df1$value))
```

Or calculate the position of the index in a vector.

```
df2 <- matrix(NA_integer_, 3, 2)
df2[df1$row + (df1$col - 1L) * 3L] <- df1$value
df2 <- as.data.frame(df2)
```

---

Benchmark

```
set.seed(0)
NR <- 10000L
NC <- 100L
df1 <- cbind(expand.grid(row=seq_len(NR), col=seq_len(NC)), value=
            sample(0:9, NR*NC, TRUE))[sample(NR*NC, floor(0.9 * NR * NC)),]

library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(Matrix)
bench::mark(check=FALSE,
cbindTwoStep = {df2 <- data.frame(matrix( nrow = NR, ncol = NC ))
    df2[cbind(df1$row, df1$col)] <- df1$value} ,
cbindMatTwoStep = {df2 <- matrix(NA_integer_, NR, NC)
  df2[cbind(df1$row, df1$col)] <- df1$value
  df2 <- as.data.frame(df2)} ,
cbindMatDF = df2 <- data.frame(`[<-`(matrix(NA_integer_, NR, NC), cbind(df1$row, df1$col), df1$value)),
cbindMatADF = df2 <- as.data.frame(`[<-`(matrix(NA_integer_, NR, NC), cbind(df1$row, df1$col), df1$value)),
vecIndex = {df2 <- matrix(NA_integer_, NR, NC)
  df2[df1$row + (df1$col - 1L) * NR] <- df1$value
  df2 <- as.data.frame(df2)},
pivot = {df2 <- df1 |> 
  arrange(row, col) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = value) |> 
  select(!row)},
data.table = df2 <- dcast(as.data.table(df1), row ~ paste("Column", col))[, -1],
sparseMatrix = df2 <- as.matrix(sparseMatrix(i = df1[, 1], j = df1[, 2], x = df1[, 3])),
xtabs = df2 <- as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(value ~ ., df1)) )
```

Result

```
  expression           min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
  <bch:expr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1 cbindTwoStep     59.99ms 132.42ms     6.41     79.2MB    11.2      4     7
2 cbindMatTwoStep    8.6ms   9.48ms    92.5      21.8MB    21.6     47    11
3 cbindMatDF        8.63ms   9.51ms    61.2      21.8MB    13.8     31     7
4 cbindMatADF       8.24ms    9.4ms    95.7      21.8MB    19.9     48    10
5 vecIndex          8.12ms      9ms    97.7      14.9MB    19.9     49    10
6 pivot            97.59ms  99.75ms     9.99     92.6MB    12.0      5     6
7 data.table      171.63ms 172.34ms     5.41     88.4MB     5.41     3     3
8 sparseMatrix     23.73ms  30.18ms    17.6      38.5MB     7.82     9     4
9 xtabs               1.1s     1.1s     0.909   269.9MB     5.46     1     6
```

Filling up the values in the `matrix` using `cbind` and converting it afterwards to a `data.frame` is more performant than filling a `data.frame`. Calculating the index on a vector is slightly faster and uses the lowest amount of additional memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the benchmarks! I was also just having a look to see just how big the difference is. Subsetting across multiple dimensions is badass, I'll need to incorporate it in my own coding more often.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really is interesting, that converting to a data.frame afterwards is almost 10 times faster then filling up a data.frame.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `xtabs`, i.e.

```
xtabs(value ~ row + col, data = df1)

   col
row 1 2
  1 3 1
  2 0 4
  3 5 2
```

Comment: The only disadvantage, beside summing up in case of two same positions is, that it shows a 0 where others show `NA`.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not the fastest solution but perhaps useful if you like Tidyverse functions. The idea is to pivot the `col` column into actual columns:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(
  row = c(1,3,1,2,3),
  col = c(2,2,1,2,1),
  value = c(1:5)
)

df1 |> 
  arrange(col) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = value) |> 
  select(!row)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>     `1`   `2`
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     3     1
#> 2     5     2
#> 3    NA     4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Your output has the rows in the wrong order.

Comment: I think you should use `arrange(row, col)`.

Answer (score 2):

**using data.table**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)

dcast(df1, row ~ paste("Column", col))[, -1]

#    Column 1 Column 2
# 1:        3        1
# 2:       NA        4
# 3:        5        2
```

**sparseMatrix approach**

Note that your data looks like a sparse matrix in data.frame format, depending on your situation you could consider this as an option too.

```
library(Matrix)
as.matrix(sparseMatrix(i = df1[, 1], j = df1[, 2], x = df1[, 3]))

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    1
[2,]    0    4
[3,]    5    2
```