# filling a matrix from another vector with a different size

Tags: r, matrix

I have a problem with filling a matrix from a vector and would appreciate your expertise.  I basically have created a 2*3 matrix (this will be different sizes each time probably):

```
nu.sh <- matrix(0, 2,3)
            Horiz 000 Horiz 001 Horiz 002
Vert 000         0         0         0
Vert 001         0         0         0
```

and then I have a vector:

```
> Numb
Vert 000, Horiz 000   Vert 000, Horiz 001  Vert 001, Horiz 000   Vert 001, Horiz 001  Vert 001, Horiz 002 
            5                   5                   3                   4                    5
```

as you can see, there is nothing in the numb vector for position Vert 000, Horiz 002. I would like to fill the matrix with this vector and have Vert 000, Horiz 002 filled with 0. I also have different data sets that the matrix will have a bigger size and the locations where there is no data on the numb vector could vary as well as situations where more than one location that is empty.

Is there a way that I can have this automatically filled while the locations that don't have any info remains 0? Basically, ask for info from the numb vector, if there is replace that info with 0 and if there isn't anything, keep the 0 and move on to the next position.

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have two vectors of indices (rows, columns) for a data.frame with corresponding values, whats the fastest way to build the new data.frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75950008/i-have-two-vectors-of-indices-rows-columns-for-a-data-frame-with-correspondin)

Comment: Are your matrix and vectors named like - `nu.sh <- matrix(0, 2, 3, dimnames=list(c("Vert 000","Vert 001"), c("Horiz 000","Horiz 001","Horiz 002"))); Numb <- setNames(c(5,5,3,4,5), c("Vert 000, Horiz 000","Vert 000, Horiz 001","Vert 001, Horiz 000","Vert 001, Horiz 001","Vert 001, Horiz 002"))` ? If so, the answer will be close to the link above after splitting the names of the vector - something like `nu.sh[do.call(rbind, strsplit(names(Numb), ",\\s+"))] <- Numb`

Comment: nu.sh[do.call(rbind, strsplit(names(Numb), ",\\s+"))] <- Numb  solved my question and it works for different matrices. Thank you very much! I really appreciate it. The link doesn't work for me cause the matrix size is usually different for each of my tests and that doesn't work. Thank you for sharing though!